# One of the arrays in my Linked List are missing

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, linked-list

Here is the node of Linked List:

```
struct Node {
char data;
struct Node *next;
int pindex; //this is the first index position in parent[] which is null, next element goes here
int cindex; //this one for child array
char parent[50];
char child[50];
};
```

This is how i am creating each node.

```
struct Node *createNode(struct Node *node, char nodeData) {
if(root == NULL) {
    int i=0;
    node= malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->data = nodeData;
    while(i<50) {
        node->parent[i]= '\0';
        node->child[i]= '\0';
        i++;
    }
    node->pindex=0;
    node->cindex=0;
    node->next= malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    root=node;
    return node;
}
else if (node->data == 0) {
    int j=0;
    node->data = nodeData;
    while (j<50) {
        node->parent[j]= '\0';
        node->child[j]= '\0';
        j++;
    }
    node->pindex=0;
    node->cindex=0;
    node->next= malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    return node;
}
else
    return createNode(node->next, nodeData);
}
```

Here is my code where i am updating the values of the parent and child arrays in a particular node.

```
void insert(char a, char b) {
struct Node *pNode, *cNode;
    if (hasNode(root,a))  //check if Node with node->data ='a' exists else create it
        pNode= getNode(root,a);
    else {
        pNode= createNode(root,a);
        //addToFirst(one); No need as we already have list of all elements
    }
    if (hasNode(root, b))
        cNode= getNode(root,b);
    else
        cNode= createNode(root, b);
pNode->child[(pNode->cindex)] = b; //insert a char into child array of parent node 
pNode->cindex++;
cNode->parent[(cNode->pindex)]= a; // insert char into child array of parent node
cNode->pindex++;
}
```

**Problem is with the following section**

```
pNode->child[(pNode->cindex)] = b; //insert a char into child array of parent node 
pNode->cindex++;
cNode->parent[(cNode->pindex)]= a; // insert char into child array of parent node
cNode->pindex++;
```

as any element is inserted into the parent[] of cNode, its child[] is gone from the memory. And if i insert later anything into child, its working.

Following is the screenshot i took for this linked list, that should help. The child array is missing from the data root->next node

[[Screenshot of the data structure]](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eam6kt1rn48iw5e/Screenshot%20from%202012-12-07%2002:01:37.jpg)

Comment: What is the exact problem? What error you got?

Comment: If something is missing on DDD display, it doesn't mean that you have problem :)

Comment: is root declared globally ? If so why is it passed as a parameter in insert function to createnode? And i dont think that you can assume that node->data of node->next would be 0. You have only allocated memory and not initialised values.

Comment: @codewarrior When later in the code i try to run some computation on child array of a node, there is no array and code gets stuck. I debugged and problem is somewhere in this section itself. 

Access Denied- Root was passed because its a recursive function and the problem is not with that.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no array"? Are you getting some segmentation fault?

Comment: As Sergey suggested it might not mean that child[] is gone. DDD chose not to display it maybe. It sure is still in cnode. DDD might have chosen not to display it.